# what is difference between Alert al=new Alert(driver); al.accept() and driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Tags: selenium

```
Alert al=new Alert(driver);
```

al.accept();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much difference between the two. However one is much cleaner than the other.

Take the following code into consideration:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

This code will tell the driver to switch to the active alert present within the driver, then accept it. All in 1 easy line of code.

Now take this code into consideration:

```
Alert al = new Alert(driver);
al.Accept();
```

Here we have to create the Alert object, pass in the driver as a parameter to the constructor, and then accept the alert.

The first code segment is preferred because the way the developers have set up the driver methods is so we can chain commands together. This allows us to use a method, then pass the return immediately into another method without having to tell our code to create an object for it. The object is still created, but we (as developers) do not have to know about its existence. Therefore making our code easier to read and maintain.